# NSMutableDictionary overrides the first value

Tags: ios, xcode6, nsmutabledictionary

This is my sample code here  i calculated break time for two entries.if i add a another entries means it is overriding the previous break time ..i dont know where i am doing wrong

[This is my first sample i got this for 2 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGmRu.png)

[This is my second sample i got this for 3 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z97Pl.png)

Here is my sample code

```
NSMutableArray *arrData = [[data objectForKey:@"data"]mutableCopy];

                 NSLog(@"%@",arrData);
NSLog display this data before adding 3entry ..
                     {
    date = "2016-01-20";
    "end_time" = "11:10:00";
    "function_code" = RCV;
    "operator_id" = JOHN;
    "start_time" = "11:00:00";
    "total_time" = 10;
    "total_units" = 19;
},
    {
    date = "2016-01-20";
    "end_time" = "12:25:00";
    "function_code" = PIK;
    "operator_id" = JOHN;
    "start_time" = "12:15:00";
    "total_time" = 10;
    "total_units" = 26;
})



              NSMutableDictionary *thirdEntry = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

                 [thirdEntry setObject:@"02:00:00" forKey:@"end_time"];
                 [thirdEntry setObject:@"PUL" forKey:@"function_code"];
                 [thirdEntry setObject:@"01:25:00" forKey:@"start_time"];
                 [thirdEntry setObject:@"45" forKey:@"total_units"];
                 [thirdEntry setObject:@"20" forKey:@"total_time"];
                 [arrData addObject:thirdEntry];


                 NSLog(@"%@",arrData);



                 //dictionary
                 NSMutableDictionary *dictData =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                 NSMutableDictionary *dictData1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];




                 NSMutableArray *arrayProgressDate =[NSMutableArray array];

                  //storing the breaktime values

                 NSMutableDictionary *dictValues =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


                    for (int i =0; i<arrData.count; i++) {

                        dictData =arrData[i];

                        [arrayProgressDate addObject:dictData];

                        NSString *strendTime1 =[dictData objectForKey:@"end_time"];

                        NSLog(@"%@",strendTime1);



                            [dictValues setObject:strendTime1 forKey:@"end_time_value"];




                        if ((i + 1) < arrData.count) {


                            dictData1=arrData[i+1];



                            NSString *strStartTimeNext = [dictData1 objectForKey:@"start_time"];

                            NSLog(@"%@",strStartTimeNext
                                  );
                            //[arrayProgressDate addObject:strStartTimeNext];
                           [dictValues setObject:strStartTimeNext forKey:@"start_time_value"];

                            //calculating  break time

                        NSDate *endTimeDate = [[DateHelper sharedHelper ] dateFromString:strendTime1 withFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
                        NSDate *startTimeDate = [[DateHelper sharedHelper]dateFromString:strStartTimeNext withFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];


                            NSTimeInterval timeElapsedInSeconds = [endTimeDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimeDate];

                        double hours = timeElapsedInSeconds / 3600.0;
                            NSLog(@"%f",hours);


                        int breakTimeInMinutes = timeElapsedInSeconds/60;
                            breakTimeInMinutes =ABS(breakTimeInMinutes);

                            NSString *newStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",breakTimeInMinutes];

                            NSLog(@"%@",newStr);

                        [dictValues setObject:newStr forKey:@"break_time"];


                            [arrayProgressDate addObject:dictValues];

                        }

                        NSLog(@"%@",dictData);



                    }




                 NSLog(@"%@",arrayProgressDate);
```

Please say me what i am doing wrong in this , i want to calculate break time.

Comment: hey, i think dictionary you were added that are not nsmutabledictionary so that can't be change. you need to make them mutable dictionary

Comment: @Sachin Patil, all dictionaries which i used here is NSMutabledictionary only .

Comment: Please say what i am doing wrong in this ,if i have 2 entries means,it is answer is correct,if having 3 entries means wrong value. please ,help me to do this

Comment: Anybody please help me to do this ,thanks in advance

Comment: As per your question , the array you finally get is this                                   - {
    "end_time" = "12:25:00";
    "operator_id" = JOHN;
    "start_time" = "11:00:00";
    "total_units" = 45;
},
{
    "end_time" = "12:10:00";
    "operator_id" = MARIA;
    "start_time" = "12:00:00";
    "total_units" = 14;
},
{
    "end_time" = "02:00:00";
    "function_code" = PUL;
    "start_time" = "01:25:00";
    "total_time" = 20;
    "total_units" = 45;
}  . John works till 12.25 and maria works till 12.10 so break time is 15 mins. Is that right?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are you trying to do?

Comment: My final array if two entries means ,    data =     (
                {
            "end_time" = "12:25:00";
            "operator_id" = JOHN;
            "start_time" = "11:00:00";
            "total_units" = 45;
        },{break_time ="65"; startime ="12:00:00;end_time = "11:00:00";}
                {
            "end_time" = "12:10:00";
            "operator_id" = MARIA;
            "start_time" = "12:00:00";
            "total_units" = 14;
        }
    )

Comment: @Sahana Kini ,can u getting ,like this i want to for 3 rd entries also, in 3 entry array has ( {first entry),{break_time for 1st and 2nd entry},{second entry},{break_time for 2and 3 rd entry },{third entry }).

Comment: How can be break time 65?

Comment: John started from 11 , ends at 12.25. Maria starts at 12.00 and ends at 12.10. So which break time are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Sorry by mistake i wrongly typed the array will tell now

Comment: My final array if two entries means, data =({date ="2016-01-20",end_time ="11:10:00",function_code ="RCV",operator_id ="JOHN",start_time = "11:00:00",total_time="10",total_ units ="19"},{break_time =" 65",start_time ="12:15:00",end_time = "11:10:00"},{date = "2016-01-20",end_time ="12:25:00",function_code ="PIK",operator_id ="JOHN",start_time = "12:15:00",total_time="10",total_units = "26"} )

Comment: @Sahana Kini Please see my latest comments

Comment: My final array if 2 entries means, ( {first entry),{break_time for 1st and 2nd entry},{second entry},{break_time for 2and 3 rd entry },{third entry }).

Comment: the 3rd entries value is  date="2016-01-20",end_time = "02:00:00",operator_id = "01:25:00" total_time="20" total_time = "45"

Comment: @please help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

This line NSMutableDictionary *dictValues =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; should be inside for loop.

While finding the break time you must consider the date as well. Otherwise you will get wrong values.

```
NSMutableDictionary *thirdEntry = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[thirdEntry setObject:@"02:00:00" forKey:@"end_time"];
[thirdEntry setObject:@"PUL" forKey:@"function_code"];
[thirdEntry setObject:@"01:25:00" forKey:@"start_time"];
[thirdEntry setObject:@"45" forKey:@"total_units"];
[thirdEntry setObject:@"20" forKey:@"total_time"];
[arrData addObject:thirdEntry];


NSLog(@"%@",arrData);



//dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dictData =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *dictData1=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];




NSMutableArray *arrayProgressDate =[NSMutableArray array];


for (int i =0; i<arrData.count; i++) {

    dictData =arrData[i];

    [arrayProgressDate addObject:dictData];

    NSString *strendTime1 =[dictData objectForKey:@"end_time"];

    NSLog(@"%@",strendTime1);

    //storing the breaktime values

    NSMutableDictionary *dictValues =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictValues setObject:strendTime1 forKey:@"end_time_value"];

    if ((i + 1) < arrData.count) {


        dictData1=arrData[i+1];



        NSString *strStartTimeNext = [dictData1 objectForKey:@"start_time"];

        NSLog(@"%@",strStartTimeNext
              );
        //[arrayProgressDate addObject:strStartTimeNext];
        [dictValues setObject:strStartTimeNext forKey:@"start_time_value"];

        //calculating  break time

        NSDate *endTimeDate = [[DateHelper sharedHelper ] dateFromString:strendTime1 withFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
       NSDate *startTimeDate = [[DateHelper sharedHelper]dateFromString:strStartTimeNext withFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];


        NSTimeInterval timeElapsedInSeconds = [endTimeDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startTimeDate];

        double hours = timeElapsedInSeconds / 3600.0;
        NSLog(@"%f",hours);


        int breakTimeInMinutes = timeElapsedInSeconds/60;
        breakTimeInMinutes =ABS(breakTimeInMinutes);

        NSString *newStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",breakTimeInMinutes];

        NSLog(@"%@",newStr);

        [dictValues setObject:newStr forKey:@"break_time"];


        [arrayProgressDate addObject:dictValues];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",dictData);



}
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayProgressDate);
```

Comment: ,did u made change other than  NSMutablearray in my code?

Comment: you must consider date and  am/pm as well.

Comment: Why store date/times as strings?

Comment: i want to display that all in label so only

Comment: @Sahana Kini,No is not working because placing nsmutablearray will not solve this

Comment: i calculated breaktime and i am placing the caluculated breaktime in one dictionary and adfing that dictionary to array .

Comment: its works fine , for calculating the first break time,while calculating the second breaktime and i am trying to store that in dictionary overrides the first value and stores the second value in that dictionary